# Using "Visual Studio 15 2017" compiler in Visual Studio 2022 IDE

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have recently downloaded the Visual Studio 2022 IDE. During installation, I selected "Desktop development with C++" and "MSVC v141 - VS 2017 C++ x64/x86 build tools" (as answers to similar questions had suggested). I want to compile using `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..` but get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:83 (project):
  Generator

    Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

  could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
```

`cmake --help` returns a list of available generators (shortened for readability):
The following generators are available on this platform (* marks default):

```
* Visual Studio 17 2022        = Generates Visual Studio 2022 project files.
                                 Use -A option to specify architecture.
  Visual Studio 16 2019        = Generates Visual Studio 2019 project files.
                                 Use -A option to specify architecture.
  Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
...
```

This output makes me think that Visual Studio 15 2017 should be available, but it is nevertheless not being found.

`cmake --version` returns `cmake version 3.23.22060601-MSVC_2`.
How could I use the Visual Studio 15 2017 generator instead of the newest Visual Studio 17 2022?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you just want to target v141?

Comment: I am building a a library from source as per the instructions for MATLAB 2021a found at https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/447387-matlab-coder-how-do-i-build-the-intel-mkl-dnn-library-for-deep-learning-c-code-generation-and-dep
I have tried it using the newest Visual Studio generator, but this resulted in issues upon using the library in Simulink (part of MATLAB). Hence, I wanted to follow the instructions to the letter this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How could I use the Visual Studio 15 2017 generator instead of the newest Visual Studio 17 2022?

Answering this directly: find and install Visual Studio 2017. That's a bad solution, though.

> I selected "Desktop development with C++" and "MSVC v141 - VS 2017 C++ x64/x86 build tools" (as answers to similar questions had suggested)

Ah, so you *want* to target MSVC v141. No problem. Use the generator for the toolchain you already have installed (VS2022) and then tell it to use the v141 toolset with the `-T` flag, like so:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -T v141 [...other args...]
```

Comment: How does this differ from using the 2017 generator with the -T v141 argument?

Comment: It uses the 2022 compiler and generates project files compatible with that version of MSBuild.